# GEE: out of memory

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am trying to run this code in GEE but I keep getting this error: Runtime: 33m (started 2024-03-03 15:08:13 +0100)
Attempted 5 times
Error: Execution failed; out of memory. (Error code: 8).

I ran it for all the months, but only three October, November and December keep giving this error.

```
// SIAC atmospheric correction module
var siac = require('users/marcyinfeng/utils:SIAC');

// Hollstein cloud mask module
var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');

var December = ee.Filter.date('2017-12-01', '2017-12-31');

var sentinel2A_December = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
  .filter(December)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filterBounds(points)
  .map(cld.hollstein_S2(['shadow', 'cloud', 'cirrus']))
  .map(siac.get_sur)
  .median()
  .select('B1','B2', 'B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12')
  .rename('December B1', 'December B2', 'December B3', 'December B4', 'December B5', 'December B6', 'December B7', 'December B8', 'December B8A', 'December B11', 'December B12');

Map.addLayer(sentinel2A_December, {bands: "December B4,December B3,December B2", min: 0.0, max: 0.3, gamma: 1.4}, 'sentinel2A_December', false);

var areaM2 = 3626.1;

// Define the order of band names
var bandOrder = [
  'December B1', 'December B2', 'December B3', 'December B4',
  'December B5', 'December B6', 'December B7', 'December B8',
  'December B8A', 'December B11', 'December B12'
];

// Buffer each point and set properties
var bufferedCollection = points.map(function(point) {
  var bufferedGeometry = point.buffer(ee.Number(areaM2).sqrt().divide(2), 1);

  // Create a feature with buffered geometry
  var square = ee.Feature(bufferedGeometry).bounds();

  // Extract bands for the buffered region
  var extractedBands = sentinel2A_December.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: square.geometry(),
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    scale: 60,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  // Create a dictionary with ordered band values
  var orderedDictionary = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(bandOrder, bandOrder.map(function(band) {
    return extractedBands.getNumber(band); // Assuming the values are numeric
  }));

  // Copy over the properties from the original point feature
  var originalProperties = point.toDictionary();

  // Merge the ordered band values and original properties
  var finalDictionary = orderedDictionary.combine(originalProperties);

  // Create a feature with the buffered geometry, ordered band values, and original properties
  var finalFeature = ee.Feature(square.geometry()).set(finalDictionary);

  // Return the final feature
  return finalFeature;
});

// Convert the buffered collection to a FeatureCollection
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(bufferedCollection);

// Print the final feature collection
//print('Final Feature Collection:', featureCollection.first());

// Export the table to Google Drive in CSV format with specified column order
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: featureCollection,
  description: 'Ethiopia_ZSMean_DecemberS2_2017',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: ['ID', 'December B1', 'December B2', 'December B3', 'December B4', 'December B5', 'December B6', 'December B7', 'December B8', 'December B8A', 'December B11', 'December B12' ]// Include additional properties
});
```